# How to rotate a motor using Java/.net/c without using a micro controller

Tags: java, c++, c, rotation, using

How to rotate  a motor using Java/.net/c without using a micro controller?
I know the programming in Java/.net/c/c++ but I have no idea about the ports and rotating motor using the port communication.

Comment: It would depend entirely on how you planned on connecting the motor to the computer.

Comment: I suggest you contact the supplier for the motor you are using and ask them how it can be controlled programatically. If they don't know, it's unlikely we will.

Comment: You could use the parallel/serial port and one relay or one transistor to power the motor only when one pin is set.

Comment: That's not a real question, is it?

Comment: @g-makulik I am pretty sure _How to rotate a motor using Java/.net/c without using a micro controller?_ is a real question.

Comment: @Ben Why it's closed then for exactly that reason (as I already expected)?? Read the FAQ please ...

Comment: Maybe it can be moved to SE electronics ?

Comment: @g-makulik Because admins are not always right ? FAQ: _not a real question: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here_

Comment: Do you have the spec on your micro controller? (generally speaking there should be some example code that came with it from the vendor to at least get it initialized etc.)  Is your motor come with the controller? or is it a separate device u need to connect?  Most controllers you program in c (or c++).  If you need a simple console command line interface, c/c++ can get you there.  But if you are after some kinda graphical/windows user interface, maybe java/c# would be easier.  You need to do more research and try a little more yourself.

Comment: @Ben But anyway the OP gives way too less information about his particular problem to point any viable solution in any of the programming languages he mentioned. IMHO SO is more intended to be a general FAQ about particular common problems, than helping users find a way to solve their specific solution problems.

Answer (score 2):

there  is one way to do that(with out any other micro controller). the simple way to do that is to use the `speaker and/or mic ports` which use `simple dc voltage control`. but u need to control the volume from the program you write.use one of the speaker for `output signal` to motor and the mic    gives `feedback` to the computer.hope this helps

Comment: Huh, hadn't thought of that. Probably doesn't have the same sort of real-time capabilities a (non-USB) parallel port offers, however.

Comment: @Rook.Yes of course you are right.But the electrical motors are sluggish and have time constants in the order of seconds which is good enough for a computer to process. Here the motors  reaction time will be the limiting factor for control and not the speed of the speaker/mic port.

Answer (score 1):

how would you connect the motor with the computer.? If it's using usb connection then may be you have to write a driver software. Or you can use Serial communication where you'll probably have to use a microcontroller..

Answer (score 1):

First, this depends on the type of motor that you are using (AC vs. DC vs. stepper) as well as how you are interfacing with the motor. You will need some sort of power control between the controller that you are programming and the motor itself (H-bridges are one of the most common). The requirements of this controller are going to restrict what you can do.

In the simplest case you would be able to write a bit stream to a DAC (digital-to-analog converter) that is connected to a power amplifier into the motor.

Anything more complex than this and you will need either a micro or analog driver circuitry.

Comment: I just want to rotate a motor.Please provide me the detailed steps for it?

Comment: You will need to find an API for one of the outputs on the computer (USB, Audio, etc...). I am assuming that you are trying to rotate a DC motor, in which case you will just need some output and you won't have to worry about an AC drive. You can control the speed by using PWMing a bit stream. (0000 is stopped, 1111 is full speed 1010 is somewhere in between). If you can get an output like this then you should have some control over the motor assuming that there is enough power from the output that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a paralell port on your computer you can use that to control a Stepper motor for instance (and you can use a library such as RXTX to control it via Java), but you still need an external hardware as power source otherwise you may burn out your motherboard.